# Cambiar el estado de un select cuando cambie el estado de otro componente

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Tengo dos `<select>` uno para el tipo de activo(`select padre`) y el otro para seleccionar la categoria del activo (`select hijo`)

La categoria la filtro cuando el tipo de activo este seleccionado
ejemplo
Si el usuario selecciona Activo del tipo `Terreno` este solo tiene 2 hijos `1.rural` y `2.urbano`

Todo bien hasta ahí, el problema que tengo es que cuando cambio a otro `tipo de activo` estoy viendo que su subcategoria sigue aparecio el valor del estado anterior, ya que no he selecciodo una subcategoria todavia.

¿Cómo puedo hacer para limpiar el select de categoria (setear en `key=0`) cada vez que cambie el estado de `ActivoTipo`?

[image]
[image]

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

import {
  Content,
  ContentBody,
  ContentHead,
  Wrapper,
} from "../style/Content";
import ServicioDepartamento from "../services/ServicioDepartamento";
import ServicioLocalidad from "../services/ServicioLocalidad";
import ServicioUnidad from "../services/ServicioUnidad";
import ServicioActivoTipo from "../services/ServicioActivoTipo";
import Console from "../components/Console";
import ServicioInformacion from "../services/ServicioInformacion";
import ServicioActivoTipoCategoria from "../services/ServicioActivoTipoCategoria";
import ServicioActivo from "../services/ServicioActivo";

const PageActivoHome = function () {
  const PageTitle = "Activos";

  // Campos del formulario
  const [compania, setCompania] = useState("");
  const [departamento, setDepartamento] = useState("");
  const [localidad, setLocalidad] = useState("");
  const [unidad, setUnidad] = useState("");
  const [activotipo, setActivoTipo] = useState("");
  const [activotipocatego, setActivoTipoCatego] = useState(0);
  const [marca, setMarca] = useState("");
  const [modelo, setModelo] = useState("");
  const [color, setColor] = useState("");
  
  // Data desde la base de dato
  const [estado_dato, setEstado_Dato] = useState([]);
  const [estado_departamento, setEstado_Departamento] = useState([]);
  const [estado_localidad, setEstado_Localidad] = useState([]);
  const [estado_unidad, setEstado_Unidad] = useState([]);
  const [estado_activotipos, setEstado_ActivoTipo] = useState([]);
  const [estado_activotipoCat, setEstado_activoCat] = useState([]);

  async function JalarData() {
    // Informacion
    try {
      await ServicioInformacion.ObtenerLista().then((response) => {
        setEstado_Dato({ companias: response.data });
      });
    } catch (error) {
    } finally {
    }

    // Departamento
    try {
      await ServicioDepartamento.ObtenerLista().then((response) => {
        setEstado_Departamento({ departamentos: response.data });
      });
    } catch (error) {
    } finally {
    }
    // Unidad
    try {
      await ServicioUnidad.ObtenerLista().then((response) => {
        setEstado_Unidad({ unidades: response.data });
      });
    } catch (error) {
    } finally {
    }
    // Localidad
    try {
      await ServicioLocalidad.ObtenerLista().then((response) => {
        setEstado_Localidad({ localidades: response.data });
      });
    } catch (error) {
    } finally {
    }
    // ActivoTipo
    try {
      await ServicioActivoTipo.ObtenerLista().then((response) => {
        setEstado_ActivoTipo({ activoTipos: response.data });
      });
    } catch (error) {
    } finally {
    }
    // ActivoTipo Categoria
    try {
      await ServicioActivoTipoCategoria.ObtenerLista().then(
        (response) => {
          setEstado_activoCat({ categorias: response.data });
        }
      );
    } catch (error) {
    } finally {
    }
  }

  useEffect(function () {
    JalarData();
  }, []);

  const handleSumit = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let formulario = {
      idinformacion: compania,
      iddepartamento: departamento,
      idunidad: unidad,
      Idlocalidad: localidad,
      IdactivoTipoCategoria: activotipocatego,
      marca: marca,
      modelo: modelo,
      color: color,
      componentes: componente,
      serial: serial,
      observaciones: observacion,
    };
    let Data = JSON.stringify(formulario);
    ServicioActivo.Crear(Data);
  };

  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <Content>
        <ContentHead>
          <h1>Activos</h1>
        </ContentHead>
        <Console stateName={compania} />

        <ContentBody>
          <h3>Compania: {compania}</h3>
          <h3>Departamento: {departamento}</h3>
          <h3>Unidad: {unidad}</h3>
          <h3>Localidad: {localidad}</h3>
          <h3>Activo Tipo: {activotipo}</h3>
          <h3>Activo Categoria : {activotipocatego}</h3>
          <div>
            {/* Companias */}
            <div>
              <label htmlFor="idInformacion">Compañia:</label>
              {Array.isArray(estado_dato.companias) ? (
                <select
                  name="idInformacion"
                  id="idInformacion"
                  value={compania}
                  onChange={(e) => setCompania(e.target.value)}
                >
                  <option key="0" value="-- Seleccionar --">
                    -- Seleccionar --
                  </option>
                  {estado_dato.companias.map((x) => (
                    <option key={x.id} value={x.id}>
                      {x.alias}
                    </option>
                  ))}
                </select>
              ) : null}
            </div>
            {/* Departamentos */}
            <div>
              <label htmlFor="idDepartamento">Departamento:</label>
              {Array.isArray(estado_departamento.departamentos) ? (
                <select
                  name="idDepartamento"
                  id="idDepartamento"
                  value={departamento}
                  onChange={(e) => setDepartamento(e.target.value)}
                >
                  <option key="0" value="-- Seleccionar --">
                    -- Seleccionar --
                  </option>
                  {estado_departamento.departamentos.map((x) => (
                    <option key={x.id} value={x.id}>
                      {x.nombre}
                    </option>
                  ))}
                </select>
              ) : null}
            </div>
            {/* Unidad */}
            <div>
              <label htmlFor="idUnidad">Unidad:</label>
              {Array.isArray(estado_unidad.unidades) ? (
                <select
                  name="idUnidad"
                  id="idUnidad"
                  value={unidad}
                  onChange={(e) => setUnidad(e.target.value)}
                >
                  <option key="0" value="-- Seleccionar --">
                    -- Seleccionar --
                  </option>
                  {estado_unidad.unidades.map((x) => (
                    <option key={x.id} value={x.id}>
                      {x.nombre}
                    </option>
                  ))}
                </select>
              ) : null}
            </div>
            {/* Localidad */}
            <div>
              <label htmlFor="idLocalidad">Localidad:</label>
              {Array.isArray(estado_localidad.localidades) ? (
                <select
                  name="idLocalidad"
                  id="idLocalidad"
                  value={localidad}
                  onChange={(e) => setLocalidad(e.target.value)}
                >
                  <option key="0" value="-- Seleccionar --">
                    -- Seleccionar --
                  </option>
                  {estado_localidad.localidades.map((x) => (
                    <option key={x.id} value={x.id}>
                      {x.nombre}
                    </option>
                  ))}
                </select>
              ) : null}
            </div>
            {/* Activo Tipo */}
            <div>
              <label htmlFor="activotipo">Tipo de activo:</label>
              {Array.isArray(estado_activotipos.activoTipos) ? (
                <select
                  name="activotipo"
                  id="activotipo"
                  value={activotipo}
                  onChange={(e) => setActivoTipo(e.target.value)}
                >
                  <option key="0" value="-- Seleccionar --">
                    -- Seleccionar --
                  </option>
                  {estado_activotipos.activoTipos.map((x) => (
                    <option key={x.id} value={x.id}>
                      {x.nombre}
                    </option>
                  ))}
                </select>
              ) : null}
            </div>
            {/* Activo Tipo Categoria */}
            <div>
              <label htmlFor="idActivoTipoCategoria">
                Categoría:
              </label>
              {Array.isArray(estado_activotipoCat.categorias) ? (
                <select
                  name="idActivoTipoCategoria"
                  id="idActivoTipoCategoria"
                  value={activotipocatego}
                  onChange={(e) =>
                    setActivoTipoCatego(e.target.value)
                  }
                >
                  <option key="0" value="0">
                    -- Seleccionar --
                  </option>
                  {estado_activotipoCat.categorias
                    .filter(
                      (item) =>
                        item.idActivoTipo === Number(activotipo)
                    )
                    .map((x) => (
                      <option key={x.id} value={x.id}>
                        {x.nombre}
                      </option>
                    ))}
                </select>
              ) : null}
            </div>
          </div>
          <br />
          <br />
          <br />
          <br />

          <label htmlFor="marca">Marca:</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="marca"
            id="marca"
            value={marca}
            onChange={(e) => setMarca(e.target.value)}
          />

          <label htmlFor="modelo">Modelo:</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="modelo"
            id="modelo"
            value={modelo}
            onChange={(e) => setModelo(e.target.value)}
          />

          <label htmlFor="color">Color:</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="color"
            id="color"
            value={color}
            onChange={(e) => setColor(e.target.value)}
          />

          <button onClick={handleSumit}>Registrar</button>
        </ContentBody>
      </Content>
    </Wrapper>
  );
};
export default PageActivoHome;
```

Comment: No se si es problema de indentación o que... pero no entiendo... porque tienes 2 funciones `function ManejadorDeCambiosFormulario(e)` y una está dentro de la otra?

Comment: sorry pegé 2 veces, al intentar pasar el codigo de vscode al stackoverflow, ya lo actualizé

Comment: No tengo mucho tiempo para escribirte la respuesta... pero deberías entonces cambiar los select de "uncontrolled" a "controlled", para que puedas setear el valor del select. Y cuando cambia el valor del tipo, pues reseteas el valor de la categoria.

Comment: Gracias por responder aprecio mucho tú tiempo. tengo un par de dudas 1. Por que dices que se encuentran en estado `uncontrolled`.  Lo tiene `Controllado` `onChange={ManejadorDeCambiosFormulario}` 2. pero como reseteo el valor de la categoria

Comment: el onchange solo te notifica cuando el valor cambia... pero eso no permite que tu le asignes un valor por código

Comment: Entiendo ya actualizé el codigo, ahora si tengo `componentes controlados`. En los selects hay 2 estado no sé si eso se puede hacer, un estado es para almacenar una lista que viene desde la base de datos, y el otro estado es para controlar dicho componente. Cómo puedo setear el valor del select?